# Why do I get error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" when running PostgreSQL UPDATE in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to update a couple of tables in a PostgreSQL database. It is in Django. But I get the following error:
`not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Why does this code throw this error? :

```
def deleteObj(param_ilid):
        try:
            sql =  "update db.tablex set enabled = 0 where objId = %s;"
            sqldata=(param_ilid)
            cursor = db.cursor('mydb',sql,sqldata)
            result = cursor.connect()
            sql =  "update db.tabley set objId = 1 where objId = %s;"
            sqldata=(param_ilid)
            cursor = db.cursor('mydb',sql,sqldata)
            result = cursor.connect()
            status = "OK!"
        except Exception as e:
            result = e
            status = "ERROR!"
        return result, status
```

Keep in mind that I'm pretty new to Django and Python. I also replaced the db name and table names with dummy names for security reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
sqldata=(param_ilid,)
```

---

Note the difference between

```
>>> type((10))
<class 'int'>
```

and

```
>>> type((10,))
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it soon and come back with how it went.